# How to use NNJoin in Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to be able to run the NNJoin plugin via the QGIS python console to run a number of times for polygon-polygon and polygon-point (all shapefiles). I gather from reading a few other questions/answers around the subject that I first need to know the module? I would imagine there's a bunch of other code too? Can anyone help point me in the right direction?